# Is it possible to have a send push notifications locally from the app?

Tags: ios, uikit

Is it possible to write an app for iOS that is capable of sending local push notifications to user without a remote server?

For example, if I have a 100% local application, can I make it to slow me a notification, let's say, every day at 10PM? Is it possible to have a background service, or schedule a task of some sort locally in iOS?

All of the tutorials I can find online make use of a remote Push API service. Does it mean, there is no way to have this functionality locally?

Comment: If there is no remote server then what are you trying to push from? If you want it all local then start here: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/ good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called local notifications. Read the [notifications for developers](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/) guide.

You schedule a user notification request using `UNNotificationRequest`. Provide a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` or `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` object as the trigger, depending if your need.

If you need iOS 9 and below support, there is an analogous `UILocalNotification` API that is deprecated in iOS 10, but can be used in case backward compatibility is needed.